# Fedora configuration for latest sofware

Tags: fedora, repository, version, dnf

I just switch from debian stable to fedora 30 to have more up-to-date software, but it seems I didn't configure it in the right way

**Example octave**

In debian I installed octave via flatpak, its version was the latest 5.1.
On fedora, the octave's version in the repository (that is using dnf install octave) is 4.4 ...
Of course I can install octave-5.1 from flatpak on fedora but this is not my idea. Did I forget to configure fedora to obtain the latest version of any software (like an equivalent of the backports repository) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Fedora 30 currently offers `octave-4.4.1` which you seem to have already found.

I could only find `octave-5.1.0` packaged for Fedora Rawhide (testing).  You could try to download the source RPM from Rawhide and attempt to build it on Fedora 30 to see what happens.

[Looking at this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1680479), it looks like `octave-5.1.0` will soon be released for both Fedora 29 and Fedora 30.